# This context in RxJS

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, rxjs, observable

I have a little problem with RX.JS. I have some kind of service and I want to send method of this service to the flatMapLatest method. The documentation says that second argument of the flatMapLatest method is thisArg. But that thisArg is not working.

```
class service {
  constructor() {
    this.val = 2;
  }

  someMethod(x) {
    console.log(this.val);
    return Rx.Observable.range(x, this.val);
  }
}

const someService = new service();

const source = Rx.Observable
    .range(1, 2)
    .flatMapLatest(someService.someMethod, someService)
```

I've created a plunker for this problem:
https://plnkr.co/edit/EOo2qlqPetUb8IGzQJea?p=preview

The only solution I found that is working is:

```
    .flatMapLatest(someService.someMethod.bind(someService))
```

So this is a issue with Rx.JS that thisArg is not working or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you try `.flatMapLatest(someService.someMethod, null, someService)` ? Looking at the source code, it seems that the function actually takes three arguments.

Comment: Yeah, It is working. I should check sources too. Thanks.